# How to fail NUnit test by default (I want to call Assert.Pass when it should pass)

Tags: c#, unit-tests, nunit

I have medium level experience on unit testing and now I'm learning about NUnit.

As far as I can see, a NUnit test passes by default if you don't call Assert.Fail method.

In my test case, I want it to fail by default unless I call Assert.Pass method.

How can I do that if it's possible?

**Simplified Example**

Current behavior:

```
// This test passes
public void Test1()
{
}

// This test fails
public void Test1()
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

The behavior I want:

```
// This test must fail
public void Test1()
{
}

// This test must pass
public void Test1()
{
    Assert.Pass();
}
```

**Detailed Example for curious cats**

The last line of this test looks unnecessary to me. I would like to remove Assert.Fail() call at the end if it was possible to mark the test as "fail by default" somehow. Maybe a parameter for [Test] attribute???

```
[Test]
public void SetValue_RaisesChangedEvent()
{
    var Property = new Property();
    Property.Changed += (Sender, Args) => Assert.Pass();

    Property.SetValue(1);
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you're wanting this type of functionality? If anything, this should be an Inconclusive test but I do not see the need to fail a test that hasn't been properly written. Understanding your need will likely result in a better answer.

Comment: My actual test method won't be empty. I just simplified the example to better explain what I need.

Comment: I think you have simplified your example too much, in that it is not clear why you would want a test to fail if it ran without "error".  Something that may not be obvious if new to NUnit: if your test has an unhandled exception, then the test will Fail, regardless if you have an Assert line or not.  It is considered bad practice to forgo having an Assert at end of test though.

Comment: Every test should assert something at last which is  the main test objective without it the test is meaningless.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I'm a minimalist programmer. I don't write any extra word in my code unless it's mandatory for compiler and runtime. Since the test passes by default, I don't call Assert.Pass at the end of the test.

Comment: @evets17 You are right. I'll edit my question to give a better example.

Comment: FWIW, the question is not completely invalid. In my case, I'm trying to ensure that all properties of an object are decorated with an attribute and the attribute has a property matching a specified value. My current attempt "queues up" all the assertions I want to run (sort of like an "assertion builder" type object)--but I'm looking for a way to ensure that all the assertions are in fact executed in order for the test to be a valid test, i.e. the test will fail unless a certain method is executed which results in my "queued up" assertions to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my original answer as I incorrectly stated that test would continue after Assert.Pass() call.

http://nunit.org/docs/2.5/utilityAsserts.html

Your specific example could be re-written like this as well to avoid the strange Assert.Fail() call at end.

```
[Test]
public void SetValue_RaisesChangedEvent()
{
    var eventFired = false;
    var Property = new Property();
    Property.Changed += (Sender, Args) => eventFired = true;

    Property.SetValue(1);
    Assert.IsTrue(eventFired);
}
```

One could say, by default this test will fail, unless the Property.Changed event fires.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Assert.Pass and Assert.Fail throws an exception which breaks the execution of the test method.

Comment: you are right, edited my response to be accurate on that front.  I guess I didn't answer question, but I would caution getting too fancy with trying to limit lines of code where a couple added lines can aid in others better understanding of the intent.

Comment: That's a different approach to the problem but the problem still exists therefore, this is not the answer to my question. Thank you for your answer anyways.